# Error in React-Router: 'Type expected. TS1110' after deleting my node_modules folder and package-lock.json

Tags: reactjs, typescript

My project was working perfectly well but I went and accidentally deleted my node_modules folder and package-lock.json and then reinstalled everything using `npm install` and now I'm getting this error

```
Type expected.  TS1110

    149 |     failed: true;
    150 | };
  > 151 | declare type ParamParseSegment<Segment extends string> = Segment extends `${infer LeftSegment}/${infer RightSegment}` ? ParamParseSegment<LeftSegment> extends infer LeftResult ? ParamParseSegment<RightSegment> extends infer RightResult ? LeftResult extends string ? RightResult extends string ? LeftResult | RightResult : LeftResult : RightResult extends string ? RightResult : ParamParseFailed : ParamParseFailed : ParamParseSegment<RightSegment> extends infer RightResult ? RightResult extends string ? RightResult : ParamParseFailed : ParamParseFailed : Segment extends `:${infer Remaining}` ? Remaining : ParamParseFailed;
```

This is the tsconfig that is in my project. It's the same as it was before when it was working

```
{
  "compilerOptions": {
    "target": "es5",
    "lib": [
      "dom",
      "dom.iterable",
      "esnext"
    ],
    "allowJs": true,
    "skipLibCheck": true,
    "esModuleInterop": true,
    "noImplicitAny": false,
    "allowSyntheticDefaultImports": true,
    "strict": true,
    "forceConsistentCasingInFileNames": true,
    "module": "esnext",
    "moduleResolution": "node",
    "resolveJsonModule": true,
    "isolatedModules": true,
    "noEmit": true,
    "jsx": "react",
    "downlevelIteration": true,
  },
  "include": [
    "src"
  ]
}
```

Output of `tsc -v` is `Version 4.5.5`. Output of `node -v` is `v16.13.0` if that is of any use. I'm thinking I might have broken something related to the TS compiler? I don't think the problem is with the react router library...

Answer (score 6):

Fixed by uninstalling and reinstalling TS using

```
npm uninstall typescript --save

npm install typescript --save-dev
```

Answer (score 0):

If you are using Visual Studio, and combine front-end with backend in one solution, you should check if the version of package Microsoft.TypeScript.MSBuild is up to date.

Answer (score 0):

I have fixed the error by doing the following in my project with storybook

```
npm i react-router-dom@5.3.0
npm i @types/react-router-dom@5.3.0
```

Answer (score 0):

Not sure if it's the right way but I solved it by deleting `node_modules/@types/react-router` folder.